# Adding image to a plot -matplotlib PYTHON

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to insert a .png image to the right side of the plot and following the code mentioned here:
[Combine picture and plot with Python Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765056/combine-picture-and-plot-with-python-matplotlib)

Here is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib._png import read_png
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage 
cmap = mpl.cm.hot
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-1 * outlier, vmax=outlier)
cmap.set_over('green')
cmap.set_under('green')
cmap.set_bad('green')
plt.xlim(0,35)
plt.ylim(0,35)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
cb_ax=fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
img = ax.imshow(np.ma.masked_values(data, outlier), cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none',vmax=outlier)
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cb_ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, extend='both')
##axim = plt.subplot2grid(shape, loc, rowspan=1)

## phlo tree
image_file = cbook.get_sample_data('mytree.png',asfileobj=False)
image = plt.imread(image_file)
phyl_ax=fig.add_axes([0.10,0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
phyl_ax.imshow(image,interpolation='nearest')
```

Th heat map would be on the left side and the image of a tree will be inserted on the right side. With the above code here is what I get...

[image: Image not added properly:-----]

[image: Here is the image I am trying to add:----]

There is something being added to the right side but obviously it isn't the way it should look like.
At first I thought I was setting the dimensions of phyl_ax too small but when I try to increase it, even the previous "something" is also not being added.

Could someone point at where I am going wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling both `subplots`, which, by default, gives you a single axes, and also adding axes via `add_axes`. You should do one or the other, e.g.

```
...
fig = plt.figure()
ht_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8])
cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.45, 0.3, 0.02, 0.4])
phyl_ax = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8])

...
```

--or--

```
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
ht_ax = ax[0]
phyl_ax = ax[1]
cb_ax=fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.3, 0.02, 0.4])

...
```

You can use [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) and [`set_aspect`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) to adjust the layout. You can also use [`colorbar.make_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes) to get an appropriately sized colorbar axes. Here I also used [`grid_spec`](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html) to get the plots to be a size ratio I liked

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 2]) 
ht_ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
phyl_ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
cb_ax, kw = mpl.colorbar.make_axes(ht_ax, shrink=0.55)
...
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax=cb_ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, extend='both', **kw)
```

Comment: Sorry I need a small clarification. There is an axis I use with imshow for the heat map, so according to your 1st solution I should add this axis too before using it?