# How can I plot an image in Python in 3D?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, plotly

Inserting an image into a 2d chart using Python has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3765056/3491991)... how do I do this in 3d? Looking for something like this (image comes from a [MATLAB example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719528/3491991))...

[image: Image plotted in 3D chart using MATLAB]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how plotly has designed the image insertion, its more of adding a background image to the plot. Please refer the below example of what can be achieved using `images` property of `layout` object. To know more read [here](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-images)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)



x, y, z = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 200).transpose()
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
            width=0.5
        ),
        opacity=0.8
    )
)

x2, y2, z2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 200).transpose()
trace2 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x2,
    y=y2,
    z=z2,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color='rgb(127, 127, 127)',
        size=12,
        symbol='circle',
        line=dict(
            color='rgb(204, 204, 204)',
            width=1
        ),
        opacity=0.9
    )
)
data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    ),
    xaxis= dict(visible = False),
    yaxis= dict(visible = False),
    images= [dict(
                  source= "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
                  xref= "x",
                  yref= "y",
                  x= 1,
                  y= 3,
                  sizex= 4,
                  sizey= 4,
                  sizing= "stretch",
                  opacity= 0.3,
                  layer= "below")]
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot( fig )
```

[image: plotly insert image]

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't get your code to execute. Does this solution change the perspective of the image by rotating the chart or does it just stay in the background as 2d? I really need the image to rotate as well